# dataframe to list of dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":[2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022, 2022],"region":['europe','USA','africa','europe','USA','africa','europe','USA','africa'],'volume':[1,6,5,3,8,7,6,3,5]})
```

[image]

I wish to convert it to a list of dictionary such that the year would be mentioned only once in each item. Example

```
[{'year':2020,'europe':1,'USA':6,'africa':5,}...]
```

when I do:

```
df.set_index('year').to_dict('records')
```

I lost the years and the list

Comment: don't you just want `df.to_dict("records")` without setting the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach that uses pivot before `to_dict(orient='records')`

```
df.pivot(
    index='year',
    columns='region',
    values='volume'
).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')

#Output:
#[{'year': 2020, 'USA': 6, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 1},
# {'year': 2021, 'USA': 8, 'africa': 7, 'europe': 3},
# {'year': 2022, 'USA': 3, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 6}]
```

Comment: Please ignore my answer below and use this one :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
d = [
    {"year": y, **dict(zip(x["region"], x["volume"]))}
    for y, x in df.groupby("year")
]

print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"year": 2020, "europe": 1, "USA": 6, "africa": 5},
    {"year": 2021, "europe": 3, "USA": 8, "africa": 7},
    {"year": 2022, "europe": 6, "USA": 3, "africa": 5},
]
```

Comment: Nice one, I like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use groupby on year and then zip region and volume

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year":[2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022, 2022],"region":['europe','USA','africa','europe','USA','africa','europe','USA','africa'],'volume':[1,6,5,3,8,7,6,3,5]})

year_dfs = df.groupby("year")
records = []
for year, year_df in year_dfs:
    year_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(year_df["region"], year_df["volume"])}
    year_dict["year"] = year
    records.append(year_dict)
""" Answer
[{'europe': 1, 'USA': 6, 'africa': 5, 'year': 2020},
 {'europe': 3, 'USA': 8, 'africa': 7, 'year': 2021},
 {'europe': 6, 'USA': 3, 'africa': 5, 'year': 2022}]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

To break down each step, you could use pivot to group your df to aggregate the years, your columns become countries, and volume becomes your values

```
df.pivot('year','region','volume')

region  USA  africa  europe
year                       
2020      6       5       1
2021      8       7       3
2022      3       5       6
```

To get this into dictionary format you can use the .to_dict('index')
command (in one line)

```
x = df.pivot('year','region','volume').to_dict('index')

{2020: {'USA': 6, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 1}, 2021: {'USA': 8, 'africa': 7, 'europe': 3}, 2022: {'USA': 3, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 6}}
```

finally you could use list comprehension to get it into your desired format

```
output = [dict(x[y], **{'year':y}) for y in x]
[{'USA': 6, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 1, 'year': 2020}, {'USA': 8, 'africa': 7, 'europe': 3, 'year': 2021}, {'USA': 3, 'africa': 5, 'europe': 6, 'year': 2022}]
```